# Error "unrecognized selector sent to instance" when trying to use UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift4, nsuserdefaults, unrecognized-selector

I am trying to store a custom object into UserDefaults using this method mentioned in another answer.

```
 var userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
 let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: categories[indexPath.row])
 userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "selectedCategory")
 userDefaults.synchronize()
```

and am retrieving them like this

```
if let category = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "selectedCategory") as? Data {
    self.categoryDisplayed = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: category) as! Category
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

however, in doing this I am arriving at an error of "unrecognised selector sent to instance". Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: What's the full error message? It should give useful information.

Comment: Unrelated but **never** use `value(forKey` in `UserDefaults` unless you can explain why KVC is needed explicitly. Use always `object(forKey` and in this case there is even specific `data(forKey`

Comment: @Larme this is the full message "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Category initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000166e840'"

Comment: It seems you didn't made your `Category` `NSCoding` compliant. That's what is missing. If it's from a JSON object, what about using Codable (because it translate `CustomClass` to `Data` according to a "JSON protocol"). `NSCoding` does it too, but can manage non-JSON properties (if possible).

Comment: @Larme Actually, the Category class is made from CoreData. It's a core data entity

Comment: And why do you save them into `NSUSerDefaults`? Also, `NSMangedObject` aren't `NSCoding` compliant, I think there is an internal code that translate them into `Data`.